# How to query for shared VPC networks?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-api-client

How do I view the list of networks/subnetworks available to me from a shared VPC? The following only returns the list of subnetworks in the current project and not shared to it:

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
compute = build('compute', 'v1')
compute.networks().list(project='project').execute()
compute.subnetworks().listUsable(project='project').execute()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking into consideration that [all of the existing VPC networks in the host project are Shared VPC networks](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/shared-vpc#shared_vpc_networks) you can use the [getXpnHost method from the REST API](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects/getXpnHost#examples_1) to get the shared VPC host project that your project links to and from there use the same [networks().list()](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/networks/list) and [subnetworks().listUsable()](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/subnetworks/listUsable) to get the desired information.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunate that this seems like the only way